# Update Data Grid View in a form by filling another form

Tags: vb.net-2010, vb6-migration

I have two forms.. form1 and form2 in form1 I have a Data Grid View with 2 columns and a button say Btn1 and in form2 I have two Textboxes and a button say Btn2 ..

Now I will open form1 and press Btn1 (I am not filling the form 1 Data Grid View here). With Btn1 Form 2 will be showed. I will enter data into the 2 textboxes and press Btn2 now I need the Data Grid View in form 1 to be filled with this data.

If possible Please tell me how to do it using a Data Table.
I am using VB.net 2012 Please help me with this. I am new to VB.net..TIA

Answer (score 0):

I assume form1's datagridview is bound to a datatable. You can define a property in form2 through which you will pass the datatable from form1 to form2. When form2 fills the datatable,  the data should appear in the datagridview in form1.